# Почему изменился цвет изображения FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, xml, android-button

В приложении под Android в одном из фрагментов у меня была FloatingActionButton. В ней было изображение из ресурсов (drawable), это изображение было синего цвета. После изменения в приложении minSdkVersion с 19 на 21, изображение во FloatingActionButton изменилось с синего цвета на чёрный.
Вот как это выглядит в layout'e фрагмента:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_star"
                style="@style/FloatingButton"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_star"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/c_green"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/rv_categories"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="right|bottom" />
```

Также изменились цвета изображений во всех кастомных FloatingActionButton (тоже стали чёрными).
Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема??

Comment: покажите пожалуйста скриншоты поведения, чтобы было нагляднее, и так же покажите ваши стили и drawable файл

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `android:tint="#0000ff"`